# For the exponential operator $e^{f(x)\frac d{dx}}= \sum_{i=0}^\infty F_i(x) \frac{d^i}{dx^i}$, is there a formula for the $F_i$ in terms of $f$?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

Consider the operator $$ e^{ f(x) \frac{d}{dx} } = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{i!} \left(f \frac{d}{dx} \right)^i $$
If one commutes the derivatives with the powers of $ f $, then there are functions $ F_i $ so that:
$$
e^{ f(x) \frac{d}{dx} } = \sum_{i=0}^\infty F_i(x) \frac{d^i}{dx^i}
$$
Is there some a formula for the $ F_i $ in terms of $ f $?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a nice closed form. I can generate them for any $i$, and they involve binomial coefficients galore with no real appant pattern.

Comment: Well that was a lie. I just worked out what the powers were, to actually make $F_i$ is another story.